# CConvertException in Play! Framework

Tags: java, templates, exception, playframework

I'm fixing up a HTML template for rendering a PDF file. The problem is that the new code I'm using works for one template but throws a `CConvertException` in another. The console doesn't give me any hints other than the following error:

`Oops: CConvertException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception CConvertException:
ERROR: An unhandled exception occured: ERROR: An Exception occured while reconstructing the pdf document: ERROR: An unhandled exception occured: null`

The new code involves using a new Java Extension that converts a `String` into another, as follows:

`#{if person?.name != null} ${person?.name.getInitials().toString()} #{/if}`

For some reason, this exact code breaks one template but works just fine in another. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you give some more info about the templates? Is it always the same template that fails? `null` might mean that there is something wrong with the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know for sure if this is the cause, but your use of the safe navigation operator `?.` is kind of weird here. And wouldn't `getInitials()` automatically return a `String`?

Why not just write (without the surrounding `if` statement):

```
// Returns the name or an empty String if name or person is null.
${person?.name?.getInitials() ?: ""}
```